# Rails 3 and Devise, Admin manages all about users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a little app with Rails and Devise, and until now we were registering new users by Rails console. Now I have been asked to give a view for admin only, where they can signup, delete and view other Users.

My question is, which is the best way to go from here with Devise to accomplish this? I have checked similar questions here,  on Devise wiki and other sites, and the conclusion I take from them is to have my own User controller.

What I need basically is a index view to list all users with a link on each one of them for editing and destroy and a new view for signup users. How much code from devise controllers I will new to override?
Also, my user model has the devise module: :database_authenticatable, :registerable,     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like ... you just want have a client side for devise, (the user needs to register, login, etc. because they cant use the console). What I think your asking for, i think you should follow this tutorial to set up devise https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise/wiki/Tutorial-%28Walkthrough%29 , (i followed this up to Set Up Subdomains, because that is what was important for me in my rails app). It should set up the functionality you are talking about. After you do this, if you find sign out throws an error, change

```
devise_for :users
```

in your routes, to

```
devise_for :users do
  get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

If this wasn't what you were looking for, go into a little more detail

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have been checking a bit this about subdomains and it is similar of what I was thinking, but I need to be more restrictive because no one except one admin will be the one who can create and destroy users. A normal User, will be able to use the web functionality, but nothing about user management. Basically the app has to be more restrictive, and Admin hast to control everything. I will check the tutorial more deeply in the next days and see how to change Devise to manage that. Thank your for your help.